# How to understand Abigail's reply to Dani's question?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, the-man-in-the-moon

In *The Man in the Moon (1991)*, *Dani* asks her mother *Abigail* about her father & church.

> Dani:  Why does he call it church when it's not?
>
> Abigail: Because when he asked my daddy if he could marry me. My daddy
>   said only if he agreed to find the Lord.